# How to configure/install MDM server for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, enterprise, mdm

I want build and run an enterprise APP that let me to manage my **iPhone** and **iPad** remotely.

I have gone through the **WWDC** 2010 Session Videos and found **Session 108 - Managing Mobile Devices** . **Apple** allows developers to do **Mobile Device Management**. I don't know where to start from and how to configure the **MDM** server and run successfully.

I have gone through the http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/ and some the tutorials [MDM](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_MDM.pdf) but no luck.

Please can someone, give me the detailed information to setup and use **MDM** server with **iPhone** and **iPad**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MDM, You have to provide push notification service, you can use it from apple by APNS and you have setup your onw server to send notification to Device. You can read more about it from [this PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Business.pdf). you can refer page no. 21 for more details.
You can also refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) documents from apple.

Comment: we can just configure in our own mac system right ! don't need any mac OSX server ! Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: you requires a server for this which will communicate with apple server, which technology are you using? PHP or .Net?

Comment: My has apache installed with PHP by default.So I am going to go with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Once you have signed up for the Apple Developer Network, you can access [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW37) which provides greater detail in the specifics of setting up a profile server. [PDF here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf)