# How to install MDM profiles in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mdm, profiles

I want to develop a solution manager iPhone.As I know MDM can take it.But how can I make MDM Server.How to generate/install iPhone MDM profiles.

What should I do?

Please help me.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

To build the MDM server you can go through the below mentioned steps

1)Follow MDM_Protocol [pdf](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) .

2)Follow this page: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning

Then verify few things.

remove the passphrase from customerPrivateKey.pem using this command

openssl rsa -in customerPrivateKey.pem -out PlainKey.pem
Then merge your APNS certificate (for example CustomerCompanyName.pem) downloaded from the portal https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ using this command

cat CustomerCompanyName.pem PlainKey.pem > PlainCert.pem
Now this PlainCert.pem file can be used in your server as APNS/MDM certificate.

3) Follow these links [link0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441607/how-to-configure-install-mdm-server-for-iphone-and-ipad) ,[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900997/ios-enterprise-developer-account-get-device-token),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743690/generate-mdm-certificate) ,[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425093/how-to-generate-development-mdm-apns-certificate) and other questions also related to MDM  in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with an iOS device, Mobile Device Management (MDM) servers use the Apple Push Notification service.Please check  this [link](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/integration/mdm/) .

Comment: My question is how to build MDM Server.